# generate case classes from CSV in Scala

Tags: scala, pointfree

I've got a CSV response from a service and I want to generate a list of case classes. For example:

```
case class MyCaseClass(e1: String, e2: String, e3: String)

val body = getLargeCsvFromServiceOrSomething()
val elements = body.split(",")
```

Now I have an `Array[String]`. I want to take that large array and break it down into 3 element chucks, so I can generate my `List[MyCaseClass]`, where each instance take 3 elements from the array. Is there a method similar to `splitAt`, but spits every n elements? I'm sure I can do this point-free, but it's just not coming to me.

Comment: If it's a CSV, then you should have the rows separated by newlines and then supposedly three elements per line. I think it's more robust to first split by newline and then map the lines to the case class instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is `grouped`:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).grouped(3).toList
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7))
```

So your thing might be like:

```
val elements = Array("a","b","c","d","e","f")
val classes = elements.grouped(3).map{ case Array(a,b,c) => MyCaseClass(a,b,c) }    
println(classes.toList) // List(MyCaseClass(a,b,c), MyCaseClass(d,e,f))
```

Comment: ya, that's the method I was looking for. I knew it was that easy. Thanks.